# Crystal Reports 2010 groups by columns

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, report

I am creating a report that contains 8 fixed groups.  I managed to get the data displayed in columns by setting the section expert to have columns and printing **Down then Across** with the **Format Groups with Multiple Columns** setting checked.  I want to print 4 groups per column.  Is there a way to print a specific amount of groups per column?

Example:
 Group 1         Group 3
    row 1           row 1
    row 2           row 2
    row 3

Group 2         Group 4
    row 1           row 1
    row 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to get that to work was by using 4 subreports. Create a subreport for each group. Create 2 detail sections. Put Group 1 and 3 next to each other in Detail a, group 2 and 4 next to each other in Detail b. In section Expert go to Detail tab and check Format with multiple columns. Set the column width to the whole page with (8.5"). Tjis will give you the layout you want. Keep in mind, my subreports were not linked and if they are different in length it will look pretty ugly. In general the groups in CR are nested and trying to achieve a layout like yours is not easily achieved.

EDIT: After re-reading your post, I don't think there is a way to get only 4 of the 8 groups to print in a column layout. CR will take all groups if you check the Format Groups option. I haven't tried it, but you could try to do 4 groups and put the other 4 in subreports and then only check the Column layout without the groups and see if that works.

Comment: Thought about using subreports but the issue I foresee is that if the subreports grow too much they might overlap on one another...right?

Comment: It depends on where you put them. But I think it's not so much overlap as they might be different in length and then you will get blank spaces in your report.

Comment: You're right...I am getting gaps that do not look presentable.

Comment: I don't think you're going to have any luck with this layout. I created groups and then put the subreports in there and it fixes the formatting a little, but I'm not sure what consequences that may have on the data.